# how to add files to disk on laravel?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to add file to disk i got this problem

```
Call to a member function store() on string
```

here is my input

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <input type="file" name="document_suppport" class="form-control-file">
</div>
```

ana here is my controller

```
public function register(Request $request){
  if($request->has('document_suppport')){
    $request->document_suppport->store();
  }
}
```

Comment: use this : `$request->file('document_suppport')->store();`

Comment: the same problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to check it's a file with `hasFile` instead of `has`, or `$request->file('document_suppport')->isValid()`.

Example:

```
public function register(Request $request){

if($request->hasFile('document_suppport') && 
     $request->file('document_suppport')->isValid()){

        $request->document_suppport->store();

    }
}
```

Also ensure that in your blade template you have `<form enctype='multipart/form-data'...`